# How to use source maps in node js?

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I stareted my node app with `node index.js` and got the following message:

`(node:10128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: e.reduce is not a function
    at Module.te (C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\tronweb\dist\TronWeb.node.js:1:9236)`

Now I'm interessted in whats happening. I've seen that there are mapping files `TronWeb.node.js.map` in the `tronweb\dist` directory. I started again using `--inspect` and opened the chrome dev tools. But in the console I see exactly the same message.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In [Node v12.12.0+](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.12.0/) sourcemaps are supported natively. Pass `--enable-source-maps` flag to enable them.

One caveat in Node `v12.12.0` is that `Error.prepareStackTrace` will no longer be called when source maps are enabled. This was fixed in `v12.16+`.

Comment: passing it in an environment variable also works `NODE_OPTIONS=--enable-source-maps node`

Comment: Please note that this is an experimental flag and has some reported performance [issues](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41541).

Comment: I tried for hours to understand why webpack's source map isn't working for me - this simple flag just solved it.. AMAZING!!

Answer (score 7):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support

```
$ npm install source-map-support --save-dev
```

Then change your run command in package.json to:

```
node -r source-map-support/register index.js
```

(Note that you should have an index.map.js next to index.js)

Answer (score 0):

With webpack you can use `--devtools=eval-source-map` and have precise source mapping without the need of a 3rd party library or any additional node flags.